# Changing color of material ui tab label

Tags: javascript, material-ui

I tried to change the label color of tab to black but it doesn't change. Label color remains white only. Is it hard coded in material-ui only? If no, then how can I change it? This is what I tried

```
const styles = {
    tab: {
        padding: '2px 34px',
        width: '140px',
        height: '72px',
        color: '#4b4b4b'
    },
    tabItemContainer: {
        background: 'none'
    }
}
<Tabs
                        tabItemContainerStyle={styles.tabItemContainer}
                        value={this.state.selectedTab}
                        onChange={this.handleTabChange}>
                        <Tab
                            value={0}
                            buttonStyle={styles.tab}
                            label='Members'/>
                        <Tab
                            value={1}
                            buttonStyle={styles.tab}
                            label='Permissions'/>
                    </Tabs>
```

Comment: Adding !important param to hexadecimal color value does trick in this cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use the `style` property instead of `buttonStyle`

```
<Tab
   value={0}
   style={styles.tab}
   label='Members'
/>
```

Comment: what if i want to add style only on active Tab ?

Comment: You can add a conditional style if your tab value === selectedTab

Comment: actually i don't know how to get `selectedTab` because there is no such property in documentation, can you please help me out.